# SQL Query : Use CASE in a string value and where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am not good in creating queries. Can you guys help me arrange this query?

```
Select Height, Country 
CASE when Country = 'INDIA' then SUM(QTY) WHERE Country = 'INDIA'  end as INDIA,
CASE when Country = 'JAPAN' then SUM(QTY) WHERE Country = 'JAPAN' end as JAPAN
from tb_Master
```

I want to Select the SUM(Qty) of each peoples height by their respective countries. QTY represents the number of people or population

```
Height INDIA JAPAN 
4.5    120    90 
5.0    40     30 
5.3    60     70
```

Comment: can you please provide schema of tb_Master table, what is QTY ??

Comment: You have to place `CASE` inside `SUM`, like `SUM(CASE WHEN Country = 'INDIA' THEN QTY ELSE 0 END) AS INDIA`

Comment: can you describe more?

Comment: @SagarShirke : sorry for forgetting that. QTY is number of people. I actually dont need to display the qty. I only want the sum of people who have 4.5" Height by each country.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I tried that but there's an error stating Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

Comment: @Kath If you want the count of people as per their height, then this query might work for you: select height, country, count(height)
from tb_master
group by height, country

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tb_Master (height decimal(2,1), country varchar(6))
set nocount on
declare @i tinyint = 120
while @i>0
begin
insert #tb_Master values (4.5,'INDIA')
select @i -=1
end
set @i = 90
while @i>0
begin
insert #tb_Master values (4.5,'JAPAN')
select @i -=1
end
set @i = 40
while @i>0
begin
insert #tb_Master values (5.0,'INDIA')
select @i -=1
end
set @i = 30
while @i>0
begin
insert #tb_Master values (5.0,'JAPAN')
select @i -=1
end
set @i = 60
while @i>0
begin
insert #tb_Master values (5.3,'INDIA')
select @i -=1
end
set @i = 70
while @i>0
begin
insert #tb_Master values (5.3,'JAPAN')
select @i -=1
end
--select * from #tb_Master
select * from
(
select height, country, count(height) AS QTY
from #tb_Master
group by height, country
) AS table_source 
PIVOT
(
     SUM(QTY)
    for country in ([INDIA], [JAPAN])
) AS table_alias 
Print 'I suspect you will next want to perform a search for "dynamic pivot"'
drop table #tb_Master
```